# How to filter record from array of object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, notifications, mongoose-schema

Database

```
{
        "followings": [],
        "post": [],
        "saved": [],
        "tagged": [],
        "_id": "637661a7454b5127be5baeb4",
        "username": "shiv_yadav",
        "password": "12345",
        "emailorphone": "99999",
        "name": "Shiv Yada",
        "Saved": [],
        "Tagged": [],
        "__v": 0,
        "bio": "test newBiofssx",
        "profileimg": "http://localhost:4100/images/637661a7454b5127be5baeb4-shiv_yadav-1670158119497-jan-kopriva-pfsNJ0wUT5E-unsplash.jpg",
        "email": "test@test.cosmd",
        "gender": "Male",
        "notification": [
            {
                "notiticationId": "1672147216504",
                "type": "RequestedToFollow",
                "requester": {
                    "_id": "637722bdd78bd1ecef887b44",
                    "username": "vik_choudhar",
                    "profileimg": "http://localhost:4100/images/637722bdd78bd1ecef887b44-vik_choudhary-1670321337541-pexels-bess-hamiti-35188.jpg",
                    "name": "Vikash"
                },
                "readed": false
            },
            {
                "notiticationId": "1672201273818",
                "type": "RequestedToFollow",
                "requester": {
                    "_id": "63772408d78bd1ecef887b47",
                    "username": "Jay_B",
                    "profileimg": null,
                    "name": "Jay"
                },
                "readed": false
            },
            {
                "notiticationId": "1672201356611",
                "type": "RequestedToFollow",
                "requester": {
                    "_id": "6377244ad78bd1ecef887b4a",
                    "username": "Urvesh_V",
                    "profileimg": null,
                    "name": "Urvesh"
                },
                "readed": false
            }
        ],
    }
```

I am using a mongoose. I have a record of users. I am making the notification feature. I have an array of objects for notification fields. I want to update the notification status **(Here the field "readed")** for **id(1672147216504,1672201273818)** from **false to true** of any particular user. Here **id means the time field** in the object. I have read the document, but it's not updated when I update the field.

I don't know where I am making a mistake.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that?
I have tried the following code.

```
const notiticationIds = [1672147216504, 1672201273818]
const data = await user.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: userid, 'notifications.notiticationId': notiticationIds }, {
    '$set': {
        'notifications.$.readed': 'true',
    }
})
```

Comment: Please add the data as text or code, not as an image, and share the query that you tried

Comment: I have add the code and data as well. you can check sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) in order to choose the specific items to update inside the array. If you want to get back the document after the update (this is not the default), use `returnNewDocument`: `true`

```
const data = await user.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: userid,
   notification : {
    $elemMatch: {
      notiticationId: {$in: ["1672147216504", "1672201273818"]}
    }
  }},
  {$set: {"notification.$[item].readed": true}},
  {
    arrayFilters: [{"item.notiticationId": {$in: ["1672147216504", "1672201273818"]}}],
    returnNewDocument: true
  }
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oFW1UvJ1x-k)

Comment: but sir this is for MongoDB i want to do this mongoose

Comment: I have changed the database object can you please, see that again

Comment: In this query I am not able to see where you have passed the id of user.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly